# i have a question i use flick video player package in flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, flutter-video-player

**i used flick vidoe player package for flutter TV plateform it works fine on emulator but when i create a release for it and intall on phycial device it me causing lagging in video and not showing contolas on TV device

i try the of offical pub.dev package code
but just one thing i change that onEnd the video will play in loop i have links of videos last video play then first video play again and repeat process**

```
class LandscapePlayerControls extends StatelessWidget {
  const LandscapePlayerControls(
      {Key? key, this.iconSize = 20, this.fontSize = 12, this.dataManager})
      : super(key: key);
  final double iconSize;
  final double fontSize;
  final DataManager? dataManager;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const String logo = 'assets/images/logo.svg';
    FlickVideoManager flickVideoManager =
        Provider.of<FlickVideoManager>(context);
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        FlickShowControlsAction(
          child: FlickSeekVideoAction(
            child: Center(
              child: flickVideoManager.nextVideoAutoPlayTimer != null
                  ? FlickAutoPlayCircularProgress(
                      colors: FlickAutoPlayTimerProgressColors(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    )
                  : FlickAutoHideChild(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                dataManager!.skipToPreviousVideo();
                              },
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.skip_previous,
                                color: dataManager!.hasPreviousVideo()
                                    ? Colors.white
                                    : Colors.white38,
                                size: 35,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: FlickPlayToggle(size: 50),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                dataManager!.skipToNextVideo();
                              },
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.skip_next,
                                color: dataManager!.hasNextVideo()
                                    ? Colors.white
                                    : Colors.white38,
                                size: 35,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
          child: FlickAutoHideChild(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlickPlayToggle(
                        size: 20,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      FlickCurrentPosition(
                        fontSize: fontSize,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          child: FlickVideoProgressBar(
                            flickProgressBarSettings: FlickProgressBarSettings(
                              height: 10,
                              handleRadius: 10,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 8.0,
                                vertical: 8,
                              ),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white24,
                              bufferedColor: Colors.white38,
                              getPlayedPaint: (
                                  {double? handleRadius,
                                  double? height,
                                  double? playedPart,
                                  double? width}) {
                                return Paint()
                                  ..shader = LinearGradient(colors: [
                                    Color.fromRGBO(108, 165, 242, 1),
                                    Color.fromRGBO(97, 104, 236, 1)
                                  ], stops: [
                                    0.0,
                                    0.5
                                  ]).createShader(
                                    Rect.fromPoints(
                                      Offset(0, 0),
                                      Offset(width!, 0),
                                    ),
                                  );
                              },
                              getHandlePaint: (
                                  {double? handleRadius,
                                  double? height,
                                  double? playedPart,
                                  double? width}) {
                                return Paint()
                                  ..shader = RadialGradient(
                                    colors: [
                                      Color.fromRGBO(97, 104, 236, 1),
                                      Color.fromRGBO(97, 104, 236, 1),
                                      Colors.white,
                                    ],
                                    stops: [0.0, 0.4, 0.5],
                                    radius: 0.4,
                                  ).createShader(
                                    Rect.fromCircle(
                                      center: Offset(playedPart!, height! / 2),
                                      radius: handleRadius!,
                                    ),
                                  );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      FlickTotalDuration(
                        fontSize: fontSize,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      FlickSoundToggle(
                        size: 20,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          right: 20,
          top: 10,
          child: SvgPicture.asset(
            logo,
            semanticsLabel: 'Logo',
            // colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.redAccent, BlendMode.srcIn),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
class SamplePlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  SamplePlayer();

  @override
  _SamplePlayerState createState() => _SamplePlayerState();
}

class _SamplePlayerState extends State<SamplePlayer> {
  late FlickManager flickManager;
  late DataManager dataManager;
  List<String> urls = (videoData["videos"] as List)
      .map<String>((link) => link["videoUrl"])
      .toList();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flickManager = FlickManager(
        videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
          Uri.parse(urls[0]),
        ),
        onVideoEnd: () {
          dataManager.skipToNextVideo(Duration(seconds: 5));
        });

    dataManager = DataManager(flickManager: flickManager, urls: urls);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    flickManager.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  skipToVideo(String url) {
    flickManager
        .handleChangeVideo(VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(url)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FlickVideoPlayer(
        flickManager: flickManager,
        preferredDeviceOrientation: [
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft
        ],
        systemUIOverlay: [],
        flickVideoWithControls: FlickVideoWithControls(
          controls: LandscapePlayerControls(dataManager: dataManager),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class DataManager {
  DataManager({required this.flickManager, required this.urls});

  int currentPlaying = 0;
  final FlickManager flickManager;
  final List<String> urls;

  late Timer videoChangeTimer;

  // checking is there any next video
  String getNextVideo() {
    currentPlaying++;
    return urls[currentPlaying % urls.length];
  }

  // checking that the list has the next video link
  bool hasNextVideo() {
    return true; // Always return true for infinite looping
  }

  // previousVideos
  bool hasPreviousVideo() {
    return true; // Always return true for infinite looping
  }

  // the function that plays the next video in the list
  skipToNextVideo([Duration? duration]) {
    debugPrint("video next index====>>$currentPlaying");
    String nextVideo = getNextVideo();

    flickManager.handleChangeVideo(
      VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
        Uri.parse(nextVideo),
      ),
      videoChangeDuration: duration,
    );
  }

  skipToPreviousVideo() {
    currentPlaying--;
    flickManager.handleChangeVideo(
      VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
        Uri.parse(urls[currentPlaying % urls.length]),
      ),
    );
  }

  cancelVideoAutoPlayTimer({required bool playNext}) {
    flickManager.flickVideoManager
        ?.cancelVideoAutoPlayTimer(playNext: playNext);
  }
> }
```